# How do you apply a named macro to many lines in emacs without narrowing?

Tags: emacs, macros

I have a macro that I have named and saved that I would like to apply to each line of of a selection of text.

The specific macro I am using makes use of the `C-x n n` narrowing command, so I cannot use that in the function to narrow the region, since the widening command would undo any narrowing done before it.

Edit: I should specify that I would like to define an arbitrary number of lines by selecting a region, rather than using `C-u [number]` to define a number of repetitions for the macro

Comment: I would like to apply it to lines in a specific region, though. E.g., I execute `C-SPC C-s : ` to select a region until the next colon.

Comment: An answer pointing out that `C-x C-k r` calls `apply-macro-to-region-lines` was posted and then for some reason deleted; but that sounds like what you're after?

Comment: That applies the macro that you would call with `C-x e`, but not one that you had already saved in .emacs in a previous session or that had been overwritten by a newly defined macro.

Comment: Your named macro is a command which can itself be recorded in a macro, so you can simply record a macro which invokes that command, and then use `C-x C-k r` to apply it to each line of the region.

Comment: That requires invoking the command, though, and then undoing every step, which would be equivalent to `C-x ( M-x [command-name] C-u [number of total executions in unnested command] C-x u C-x ) `. And then, if you wanted to use the macro, it would overwrite whatever macro was bound to `C-x e` at the time.  Additionally, some commands could halt early if they reach a failure point early, such as a search, although I am not sure if that wouldn't cause problems either way.